# FreeForm 3.1.4 Blank page when sending

Tags: solspace-freeform

FreeForm 3.1.4
ExpressionEngine 2.5.5
Build 20121220

Hi There,

When submitting my form, it takes you to the root domain (www.domain.com) and shows a white/blank page. It is not adding the entry to the database either or at least it isn’t showing in the Entries Tab.

I have tried with no .htaccess file
Communicate tab works.

It happens on another form on the same site as well.

Any ideas? See my template code below:

```
{exp:freeform:form
           collection="Contact Form"
           required="name|email|question"
           return="/contact/thank-you"
           notify="mark@domain.com" 
           template="contact"
        }

        <p class="form-element">
            <label>Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="txtbox" />
        </p>

        <p class="form-element">
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="txtbox" />
        </p>

        <p class="form-element">
            <label>How did you hear about us?</label>
            <select name="how_hear" />
                <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Word of mouth">Word of mouth</option>
                <option value="Search engine">Search engine</option>
                <option value="Online school listing">Online school listing</option>
                <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                <option value="Press">Press</option>
                <option value="Banners">Banners</option>
                <option value="School minibus">School minibus</option>
                <option value="Toddler class">Toddler class</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select> 
        </p>

        <p class="form-element">
            <label>If other, please specify: </label>
            <input type="text" name="other" class="txtbox" />
        </p>

        <p class="form-element">
            <label>Questions or Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="question"></textarea>
        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Have you enabled php error reporting to screen? I would guess that there is a mysql/php error but your error reporting is turned down too low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved in the Solspace forums here:
http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/15814/

Basically, once debugging was enabled the blank page displays this message:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column ‘ip_address’ in ‘where clause’
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM exp_security_hashes WHERE hash=‘181350a948fdb9c1b7e2c0646bebf75b7c7c5ea1’ AND ip_address = ‘86.146.35.53’ AND date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-7200
>
> Filename: third_party/freeform/mod.freeform.php
>
> Line Number: 1106

This is an issue with EE 2.5.4+ removing the **ip_address** column from the **exp_security_hashes** table.

Upgrading to Freeform 3.1.5 or Freeform 4, which have this fixed, should resolve the issue.

Comment: Where can I get a copy of 3.1.5?

Comment: You can get it here: http://www.solspace.com/software/license/freeform_3